# Fill all cells of a matrix with the corresponding row sum

Tags: r

I'm trying to find a vectorized solution for what seems like a fairly simple task: filling all the cells of a matrix with the row sum for the corresponding row, e.g.:

```
mymat = matrix(c(80, 15, 10, 60, 30, 5), nrow=2, byrow=TRUE)
mm_rowsums = rowSums(mymat)

output = matrix(nrow=nrow(mymat), ncol=ncol(mymat))
for (row_num in 1:nrow(mymat)) {
  output[row_num, ] = mm_rowsums[row_num]
}
```

Desired result:

```
> output
     [,1] [,2] [,3]
[1,]  105  105  105
[2,]   95   95   95
```

My knowledge of the various `apply` functions is failing me though, and I can't see how to fill by row in a vectorized way.

To add a bit of real-world context, I'm trying to calculate the various steps of a chi-squared test of independence by hand for a statistics class I'm taking.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe you can use `replicate`:

```
replicate(ncol(mymat), mm_rowsums)
#      [,1] [,2] [,3]
# [1,]  105  105  105
# [2,]   95   95   95

## Or, without creating "mm_rowsums"
replicate(ncol(mymat), rowSums(mymat))
```

Comment: Thanks, I was actually hoping to do the same thing with the columns, and it looks like I can use `replicate` for both.

Answer (score 2):

Here's an option:

```
> output[,] <- mm_rowsums # this part does the same as your `for` loop
> output
     [,1] [,2] [,3]
[1,]  105  105  105
[2,]   95   95   95
```

Comment: Just to confirm my understanding, this is vector recycling, paired with the default way to fill a matrix being down the columns first?

Answer (score 1):

Obviously I would NOT do this, but since you seemed to be struggling with a way to use `apply`

> *"My knowledge of the various apply functions is failing me though, and I can't see how to fill by row in a vectorized way"*

I thought this might be useful to you:

```
t(apply(mymat, 1, function(x){ ifelse(x != sum(x), sum(x), x) } ))

#     [,1] [,2] [,3]
#[1,]  105  105  105
#[2,]   95   95   95
```